# SignalR long polling is making request frequently

Tags: signalr, long-polling

I'm using SignalR in Mono. Its working fine, but it is always using long polling. I'm still fine in going with long polling. But as far as my understanding regarding long polling, browser makes a request to the server and the server will hold that request. Once the server has to respond, it will send a respond to that request. If the request is timedout then the client will again send a request to the server. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

But in my Signalr implementation, my browser is making request every 15 seconds frequently. Not sure that the timeout for the signalr long polling is 15 seconds and if yes, i don't know a way to change the timeout. Or is this not a normal behaviour? Please help.

**Update 1:**

Please find the log entries,

[image]

To be precise, it is taking exactly 17 seconds for SignalR to make the next request. I can see a message that 'Long polling complete' from the logs. I assume that it is coming after the given request timesout. My question is, is there a way to increase this timeout?

Comment: Can you please paste the [SignalR logs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20#enablelogging) from when the browser is making the frequent requests into your question? It would also be helpful to include the network logs from your browser's F12 tools or Fiddler.

Comment: Oops.. i didnt know it was halter from SignalR. Hi Halter! can you help me on this?

Comment: SignalR does have a long polling request timeout, but its [default value is 110 seconds](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#connectiontimeout), not 17. I cannot think of any SignalR event that occurs every ~17 seconds. If you could provide a minimal sample app that exhibits this behavior on Mono, I could take a look.